# Java: How do you enforce a class type parameter to be the same as generic type specified in a generic method?

Tags: java, generics

I created a NotificationManager class, which let's you register a generic listener to some generic notification service. In the NotificationManager class I have a generic method for registering a listener with a service:

```
public static <E> void registerNotify(Class<E> type, INotificationListener<E> listener) {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    INotificationService<E> service = (INotificationService<E>) NotificationServiceFactory.get(type);
    service.registerNotificationListener(listener);
}
```

So, for some INotificationListener of a particular type I'd like to force the user, when calling this method, to specify the same type as the listener. The type maps to all the INotificationListeners of the same type, however this method doesn't enforce what I'm trying to enforce. For example, I could call:

```
INotificationListener<Location> locationListener = this;
NotificationManager.registerNotify(String.class, locationListener);
```

and the code compiles fine. What I thought this would enforce is the following:

```
INotificationListener<Location> locationListener = this;
NotificationManager.registerNotify(Location.class, locationListener);
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

---

**Update:**

Sorry for the mixup, the above does in fact work. The method in the same class which does not work is actually the following:

```
public static <E> void broadcastNotify(Class<E> type, E data)
    {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        INotificationService<E> service = (INotificationService<E>) NotificationServiceFactory.get(type);
        service.notifyListeners(data);
    }
```

And calling:

```
Location location = new Location();
NotificationManager.broadcastNotify(Object.class, location);
```

Does not cause a compilation error, which is what I would like it to do.

Comment: What is the declared return type of `NotificationServiceFactory#get()`?

Comment: It is INotificationService<?>. The factory holds a map, which maps class type names to INotificationServices. I suppose it should probably be INotificationService<E>, but how do I make sure the user gets a compilation error when they pass the wrong class in the registerNotify method?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I just get the desired compilation error when I try to pass `String.class` (Eclipse Helios SR2). Are you really running the code you think you're running? Or are you using javac or a different IDE?

Comment: I also get a compiler error when doing this, both in and out of the IDE (NetBeans 6.9.1). @Science Are you actually calling register in some less concrete way?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, long weekend. I edited my question with the correct method. The one I listed actually does work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I changed the signature of:

```
public static <E> void broadcastNotify(Class<E> type, E data)
```

to:

```
public static <E> void broadcastNotify(Class<E> type, INotification<E> data)
```

where INotification is some interface that wraps the data I'm trying to return in the notification. This enforces that the class type must exactly match the notification type so that the underlying map that maps the notifications sends the messages to the registered listeners correctly without worry of programmer error.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid the problem is to use reflection and obtain the type from the class itself. This will avoids the need to provide the same type twice. It will only provide a warning is a non-generic type is used.

You can get the generic type from the interface for the implementing class.

Comment: I chose not to go this route because of readability. If a class registers and unregisters a bunch of different types of listeners using 'this' as the listener parameter, it's hard to tell what it is registering/unregistering for notifications for.

Comment: Its it registering/unregistring the notification types it accepts. You would just have to look at the implementation.  But I agree that its best to do what you think is clearest, and least likely to result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

Location is an Object - I believe it becomes:

```
public static <Object> void broadcastNotify(Class<Object> type, Object data)
```

Remember in java all objects inherit from Object.

Comment: I know, but I would like to enforce it to be the exact same class because underneath I have a map, that maps the class to listeners of that class, so if somebody registers with registerNotify(Location.class, this), but a broadcast is written as broadcastNotify(Object.class, location) the listeners won't get the message.